# ECS Fargate Public IP connection refused

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I have a docker container that is being hosted on ECS via Fargate. The Docker container itself is in ECR. In ECS, I have a task definition that uses the image in ECR and also has a port mapping on port 80 (the port the docker image is running on). I also have a Service defined in the ECS Fargate cluster used to use the Task Definition of this image. When creating the service a new security group is created that allows all traffic from port 80(HTTP). So essentially any kind of HTTP traffic should be able to access this image using the public IP generated via the Service. For some reason, when accessing the public IP whether incognito or not, I am getting "This site can't be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have verified countless times the security group is open to allow any HTTP traffic and have also ensured the public subnet has an Internet Gateway to allow the internet. Any advice would be appreciated. Below is the Dockerfile I am using to create this image.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
ADD hello.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

**Update**
I've tried to run this image locally on my machine and am getting the same error.

Comment: does the image run fine locally and can you access it on port 80? Also, does your service have a LB or are you connecting directly to the public IP of your task?

Comment: I have not integrated a load balancer yet. I am trying to connect to it via the public IP of the task. Still getting connection refused even though port 80 is open to the world.

Comment: and if you `docker run -p 80:80 <image_name>` on your laptop it runs just fine and you can connect to `http://laptop_ip:80`? (same image you are using with Fargate of course)

Comment: What does your nginx.conf look like? You would have to make sure that the port you're using for the server is the same as the port you're exposing in your dockerfile.

Answer (score -1):

You've forgot to EXPOSE the port in the Dockerfile.

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
ADD hello.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 80
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: `EXPOSE` doesn't actually do anything, it's really just for documentation. When you publish ports it overrides the EXPOSE